# Json parsing is not that fast in titanium for large data

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working on a json but the issue I am facing is that it takes about 5 to 6 seconds while the whole data is being parsed. I googled a lot but i didn't  find any way to improve the performance

Sample Code : remove tags is my function to remove some extra data

var XMLTools = require("XMLTools");

```
            var my_json = new XMLTools(remove_tags(this.responseText, "<odds", "</odds>")).toJSON();
            var jason_data = JSON.parse(my_json);
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with any  code? for example, how do you parse json or how did you get data?

Comment: Also can you let us know the size of the JSON payload, like the size or the length of it.

Comment: iOS or Android?  If iOS, try a couple of the modules out there. I've used DZJSONKit from this list. TiNativeJSON looks to do a similar thing too : http://gitt.io/search?q=JSON

Comment: Length goes upto 100 to 150 arrays embedded with objects

Comment: Did you time if its `XMLTools`, `remove_tags` or `JSON.parse` which take up most of time?